# how to add new select box after clicking a button in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i dont know if its possible using jquery,..i have a select option that has an array of data came from database and what i want is that whenever i click a button, another select option will popout like the first select option..
here is the code of my select option

```html
       <select class="form-control" name="room[]" id="room[]">
        <option value="" default>Select</option>
        <?php
        $room = $subjectsClass->room();
        foreach ($room as $key => $value) {
        echo '<option value=" ' . $value['room_id'] .' ">' . $value['room_no'] . '</option>';
        }
        ?>
        </select>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="addRooms" >Add more Rooms?</button>
<script>

$('#addRooms').click(function(){
  //append another select box with data from database,..how??
});

</script>
```

Comment: where is your button code? you want onlick event on select box? It is possible to create select box dynamically with jquery easily.. option data u can retrive by ajax..

Comment: uhm my problem is how can i add another select box that has a fetched data from database..

Comment: Please understand that options are the things inside of selects and not the selects themselves, so when you ask "how to add new select option after clicking a button in jquery", everyone will immediately think you mean that you want a new option to appear in the dropdown, not a new select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have that wrapped into a div like:

```
<div id="the_div_of_wrapping"> all your stuff </div>
```

Then I would do:

```
var the_select = $("#room[]");
var the_id = the_select.prop("id");
var the_number_of_selects = $("select").length;
var the_div_of_wrapping = $("#the_div_of_wrapping");

the_select.clone().prop("id", the_id + the_number_of_selects);
the_div_of_wrapping.append(the_select);
```

.

### Update:

As discussed in the comments, I would remove id since it is unnecessary and then the code would be:

```
var the_select = $("#room[]");
var the_div_of_wrapping = $("#the_div_of_wrapping");

the_select.clone();
the_div_of_wrapping.append(the_select);
```

Comment: what does "the_number_of_selects" means sir ??

Comment: Well to be honest, I would just get rid of the id you have on your select. You don't need it. The problem is that it is invalid html to have the same id twice (unlike name which can be used more than once). I was only sticking with what you had. Since you can't have the same one twice, I was making sure you didn't by making the ids like room[]1, room[]2, room[]3. Like I said though, you should just drop the id. I will modify my answer to show that way as well.

Comment: i tried what u say about the id and paste your code but whenever i click the add button the first one disapper

Comment: Can you update your answer with the entire code that you just tried?

Comment: ahm actually it add now here is the code the_select.clone().appendTo(the_div_of_wrapping); but i have question sir, is the cloned select box will be send to another page when i click a submit button??

Comment: No. You have to handle this another way. You need to track this on the post.

Comment: Further questions should be addressed in a new question. Please make a new stackoverflow question if you need additional help.

Comment: oh god i suck in explaining haha so you mean i can track all cloned select box using post after submitting sir?

Comment: Sure. Since you have name="room[]", then on the backend you can grab that out of the post and it will be a list of all the selects' values and you can just create that many selects (since they are all the same) and prefill them with the values you got. I will not be answering any more questions here though. Any further questions will be ignored. If you have more questions, please create a new question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104091/discussion-between-benjamin-espanola-and-macainian).